# Rectangles instead of letters after flattening field in pdf form using iText

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I'm filling a pdf form using iText in C#. There are radio buttons and text fields to be filled and when I am done I want those fields to be uneditable - flattened. Everything works fine as long as I don't call

```
form.FlattenFields();
```

after that fields which where filled with text are broken - each letter turns into a rectangle. When I don't call form.FlattenFields() those fields are fine but still editable which is not what I want. Code:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);

PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(reader, new PdfWriter(dest));

PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdf, true);

form.GetField("question1").SetValue("Text");

form.FlattenFields();

pdf.Close();
```

Comment: Please add your document, so that we can test your code

Comment: This document was made the same way the main document was. Folder contains 3 files - empty form to be filled, result without flattening and result with flattening https://uploadfile.pl/pokaz/1699135---gvm4.html

Comment: Already in the "no_flatten.pdf" I only see those rectangles.

Comment: @J.Doe Do you still have open issues in regards to your question? Then please share them. Or does my answer sufficiently answer it? Then please mark it as accepted by clicking the tick at its upper left.

Answer (score 0):

In short: The form in your PDF is broken, it requests the use of a font without proper mapping between character codes and Unicode code points. Furthermore, all glyphs in that font are empty, so even if a PDF processor would somehow get an idea for a mapping, it would display only empty glyphs nonetheless.

Thus, a PDF processor must ignore the requests of the form and introduce its own font to fill in the form as you expect it to be filled.

#### Analyzing the form field appearance un-flattened PDF

In your question you claim

> Everything works fine as long as I don't call
>
> ```
> form.FlattenFields();
> ```
>
> after that fields which where filled with text are broken

Actually, though, already your un-flattened PDF is broken:

[image: screen shot]

And this is not due to the viewer, the appearance stream of that form field looks like this:

```
q
0 0 0 RG
0 0 151 12.36 re
S
Q
/Tx BMC
q
n
q
BT
/F0 12 Tf
4 1.32 Td
0.26667 0.26667 0.26667 rg
<0000000000000000> Tj
ET
Q
Q
EMC
```

As you see the string shown is `<0000000000000000>`, i.e. four `0000` glyphs. However that font might be encoded, this cannot represent `"Text"`.

`"Text"` in this PDF only occurs once: As value of the abstract form field. Thus, if a PDF viewer does not take the appearance given in the PDF but creates one itself (e.g. when editing the form field), it may display something representing `"Text"`.

#### Analyzing the original form

Having seen that already the original fill-in without flattening is broken and wondering what might have caused this, let's look at the form field properties.

First of all, this is the value of the **DA** (default appearance) attribute which is used in construction of the appearance stream above:

```
.266667 .266667 .266667 rg
/F0 12 Tf
```

You'll recognize both instructions (fill color definition in the former line, font and font size definition in the latter one) in the appearance stream above.

The font name **F0** both in the appearance stream resources and the default resources (**AcroForm** entry **DR**) resolves to the same font:

```
28 0 obj
<<
  /Type/Font
  /BaseFont/WRCKAA+TimesNewRomanPSMT
  /ToUnicode 29 0 R
  /Subtype/Type0
  /DescendantFonts[33 0 R]
  /Encoding/Identity-H
>>
endobj
```

The encoding is **Identity-H** which essentially means that the character codes used in the PDF are the same as the codes used in the font. Thus, no information on the actual meaning of a code.

But there is a **ToUnicode** map referenced above! Let's have a look at its contents:

```
/CIDInit /ProcSet findresource
begin
12 dict
begin
begincmap
/CIDSystemInfo <</Ordering (UCS) /Registry (Adobe) /Supplement 0 >> def
/CMapName /Adobe-Identity-UCS def
/CMapType 2 def
1 begincodespacerange
<0000> <ffff> endcodespacerange
1 beginbfchar
<0003> <0020> endbfchar
endcmap
CMapName
currentdict
/CMap defineresource
pop
end
end
```

Only one mapping, the character code `0003` is mapped to `0020`, the Unicode code point for *space*, nothing else!

**Thus, the form definition asks a PDF processor to use a specific font for filling but this font offers no information on which character codes in this font represent which Unicode value.** So a PDF processor trying to do as requested can only fail in filling the form!

Furthermore, the font has a **BaseFont** value of **WRCKAA+TimesNewRomanPSMT**. That 6 letter prefix indicates that this font is not the full TimesNewRomanPSMT but only a subset of it. so let's look at the glyph drawing information in the font:

[image: F0 characters]

and so on and so on for more than 4000 glyphs.

Thus, the font only has a non-empty drawing for the first glyph (which is named `".notdef"`, i.e. it is meant to stand in for undefined glyphs), all other glyphs are drawn empty!

Furthermore, the font contains its own information on a mapping character code to Unicode (otherwise there would not be any character headings in the table). A PDF processor is not required to use these information, but if it would have used them, it would have been fooled into using character codes which eventually all only represent empty glyphs!